# XElement.Nodes() and similar methods doesn't work

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I am new to Windows phone development and currently I am facing an issue. I am working on consuming a RESTful service for a windows phone application and I am getting a response successfuly in the format shown below

```
 <StationsResp xmlns="http://www.wmata.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Stations>
 <Station>
  <Code>A03</Code> 
  <Lat>38.9095980575</Lat> 
  <LineCode1>RD</LineCode1> 
  <LineCode2 i:nil="true" /> 
  <LineCode3 i:nil="true" /> 
  <LineCode4 i:nil="true" /> 
  <Lon>-77.0434143597</Lon> 
  <Name>Dupont Circle</Name> 
  <StationTogether1 /> 
  <StationTogether2 /> 
  </Station>
 <Station>
  <Code>A02</Code> 
  <Lat>38.9032019462</Lat> 
  <LineCode1>RD</LineCode1> 
  <LineCode2 i:nil="true" /> 
  <LineCode3 i:nil="true" /> 
  <LineCode4 i:nil="true" /> 
  <Lon>-77.0397008272</Lon> 
  <Name>Farragut North</Name> 
  <StationTogether1 /> 
  <StationTogether2 /> 
  </Station>
  </Stations>
  </StationsResp>
```

My C# code goes below to call  the service and store this response.

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.wmata.com/Rail.svc/Stations?api_key=API_KEY_CODE_OMITTED_INTENTIONALLY");

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += OnDownloadStringCompleted;
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}



 void OnDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs args)
        {

 XElement elm = XElement.Load(args.Result);

            var SearchResults = elm.Elements("Station");

}
```

My Problem is with the last line. object 'elm' has the value as per the response posted above. However, when I try to query the object elm using any methods  [like elm.Descendents(), elm.Elements()] it doesn't work.  My System.Xml.Linq reference version for windows phone is 2.0.5.0. Am I missing something else?

Following is the exact error message I get.

On watch window I see the value in object elm. But LINQ query elm.Elements("Station") errors out. The error message is "System.Collections.IEnumerator.CurrentCould not evaluate expression".

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found out the issue. There are 2 things. 1. I was missing the namespace reference and 2. Even though the debugger window didn't return any value, the value was present once I started to bind the data. Below is the updated code.

Comment: XNamespace wmata = "http://www.wmata.com";
XElement elm = XElement.Load(args.Result);

var metroStations = from station in elm.Elements(wmata + "Stations").Elements(wmata + "Station")
select new MetroStation
{
 StationCode = station.Element(wmata + "Code").Value,
LineCode1 = station.Element(wmata + "LineCode1").Value,
Name = station.Element(wmata + "Name").Value
};

StationList = metroStations.ToList<MetroStation>(); In the above code StationList had all the values even though elm.Elements() in watch window said "Could not evaluate expression"